# Clear text field box when tapped on iPhone

Tags: iphone, c, xcode, uitextfield

I have a text field that is editable by the user and it contains some example text saying "Tap here to enter details". I would like the text box to clear when the user taps it so that the user does not have to delete my example before inputting their message. Is there an easy way of doing this. The only thing I can think of is to make a separate view controller that it links to when the text box is touched buut this seems an awful way round something which I would have thought is rather simple. All help greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: How would I implement that in a .storyboard?

Comment: As a advise, You need to do some search on it before asking some such questions !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you've already got your answer, but there is an alternative using UITextField's delegate method `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` --

```
     - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

textField.text = @"";

}
```

Answer (score 4):

[image]There is a property for UITextField 
[clearsOnBeginEditing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/clearsOnBeginEditing)

Comment: Fantastic, greatly appreciated, I owe you a beer!